# How to prevent ttk.Treeview item from opening when double clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to use ttk.Treeview widget as an element of GUI. However I need to change its default behavior. How can I prevent expanding children of the parent item when it is double clicked. It should be opened only by single LMB click in the node (+) area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Bind to event
2. Return `"break"` from event handler

This prevent propagating the event to other bindings.
In your case:

```
tree.bind('<Double-1>', lambda e: 'break')
```